# Is there a way to change the order in which allure displays tests?

Tags: java, testing, allure

**The case:**

1. I have a simple test suite written in Java running 4 UI tests in browser via Selenium Webdriver.
2. I use TestNG and force tests to run in particular order via dependsOnMethods parameter.
3. I use Allure to generate a html report with test results

Let's assume that if to display tests alphabetically the order will be 1->2->3->4. And if to display them by order of execution it will be 2->3->4->1

**The problem:**
When I open allure report I see tests displayed alphabetically 1->2->3->4.

**Goal:**
I want tests to be displayed by execution order 2->3->4->1

Finally, **the Question:**
Can I force allure to display results the way I want? Currently I am out of ideas and haven't found any relevant information in documentation or the Internet.

P.S. I mean except the workaround when I tweak test names that their execution order will match alphabetical order.

Thank you.

Comment: There is an ability to sort the tests by order within a test group. Is that applicable for you?